# Need google sheets script to download QR codes as image and save to google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, qr-code

[[image: This is what I have]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZQnu.png)I am having the candidate names in A2 column. I am creating QR code for all the names in B2 column using this formula :

```
=image("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data="&encodeurl(A2))
```

I have around 500 names and their respective QR codes in both columns. Now I want to save all that QR codes as an image file(PNG/JPEG) to a folder in Google Drive with their respective names. Can anyone help me with the google app script?

I have searched a lot but all I can get is some complex scripts which I can't convert to what I need!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You do not even need to insert the QR codes into your sheet

Instead you can directly fetch them with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and save on your Drive with a simple script.

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data="+encodeURIComponent(data[i]);
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName(data[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh! thank you. It works like a charm. But what if I need to save it on a specific folder? DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderId).createFile(blob) is not working!

Comment: as `getFoldersByName` implies this method retrieves all folders with a given name (can be more than one), so you need to select one, e.g. `getFoldersByName(name)[0].createFile(blob)`. If you know the `id` of the folder it makes more sense to use `getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob)`

Comment: Where to use this function on google Sheets? I am not able to see any extension and other option  to add this scripts

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound